# What is the right way to show only group by column in datatable

Tags: c#, linq

I have below data in my Datatable

[image]

on above data, I'm filtering those records which are duplicate using below LINQ query

```
DataTable HasDuplicates = dt.AsEnumerable()
                              .GroupBy(g => g["Empolyee_CRC"])
                              .Where(c => c.Count() > 1)
                              .Select(g => g.OrderBy(r => r["Empolyee_CRC"]).First())
                              .CopyToDataTable();
```

Which returns me below data

[image]

Above data is successfully filtered but the issue which I'm facing is Budget_CRC column is not remove. So, for this I write below query and achieved my desire result.

```
DataTable HasDuplicates = dt.AsEnumerable()
                          .GroupBy(g => g["Empolyee_CRC"])
                          .Where(c => c.Count() > 1)
                          .Select(g => g.OrderBy(r => r["Empolyee_CRC"]).First())
                          .CopyToDataTable();

HasDuplicates.Columns.Remove("Budget_CRC");
HasDuplicates.AcceptChanges();
```

My question is how I get only one (Emplolyee_CRC) filtered column using my above LINQ query without writing below lines of code

```
HasDuplicates.Columns.Remove("Budget_CRC");
HasDuplicates.AcceptChanges();
```

Comment: You can't create a blank new DataTable from a LINQ query. So your `Remove` is a viable approach. You could create this table manually without that column, then use the filter-query to fill it. But that wouldn't be much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load another `DataTable` if you want your query to be returns `DataTable`

So use below query,

```
DataTable dtResult = new DataTable();
dtResult.Columns.Add("Empolyee_CRC");

DataTable HasDuplicates = dt.AsEnumerable()
                            .GroupBy(g => g["Empolyee_CRC"])
                            .Where(c => c.Count() > 1)
                            .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
                            .Select(g => dtResult.LoadDataRow(new object[] { g.FirstOrDefault().Field<string>("Empolyee_CRC") }, false))
                            .CopyToDataTable();
```

OR

```
DataTable HasDuplicates = dt.AsEnumerable()
                            .GroupBy(g => g["Empolyee_CRC"])
                            .Where(c => c.Count() > 1)
                            .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
                            .Select(g => dtResult.LoadDataRow(new object[] { g.Key }, false))
                            .CopyToDataTable();
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Edit:**

If you want to avoid creating new data table then you can simply project your selected data into list like.

In `if` below you can use any of both condition that separated with `&&` or you can use as it is. depending upon your need.

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0 && dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x["Empolyee_CRC"]).Count() > 0)
{
    var result = dt.AsEnumerable()
                   .GroupBy(g => g["Empolyee_CRC"])
                   .Where(c => c.Count() > 1)
                   .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
                   .Select(g => new { Empolyee_CRC = g.FirstOrDefault().Field<string>("Empolyee_CRC") })
                   .ToList();
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I want to avoid to create a new Datatable with column but as there is no other solution to return datatable using linq. I accepted this answer.

Comment: If you want to avoid creating new data table then I'll also have one possible solution that returns list to you. I'll  update my answer soon...stay in touch..

Comment: I appreciate it.

Comment: Appreciate your current edit. Here I've a little question according to your answer if there is no records in Datarow then its shows us the error. How we handle error in your above linq query?

Comment: You can just check data table rows count before query. Anyways I'll update my answer soon...

Comment: Let me check this. Take your time.

Comment: **Edit** section updated. kindly view `if` condition. you can use any of both condition that separated with `&&` or you can use as it is. depending upon your need. :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have wrong select statement in your LINQ, consider following example:

```
DataTable HasDuplicates = dt.AsEnumerable()
                          .GroupBy(g => g["Empolyee_CRC"])
                          .Where(c => c.Count() > 1)
                          .Select(g => g
                                .OrderBy(r => r["Empolyee_CRC"])
                                .Select(r => r["Empolyee_CRC"])
                                .First())
                          .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: well, good point.. I haven't noticed that .CopyToDataTable() is extension to IEnumerable<T> object where the generic parameter T is DataRow..

Comment: @SzymonTomczyk As I'm beginner to linq. Kindly tell me one more thing how can I compile your above code it shows me error on `.CopyToDataTable()`

Comment: @AhmerAliAhsan CopyToDataTable is not built-in Method, you should implement it using Extension methods : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/implement-copytodatatable-where-type-not-a-datarow